# Pi Appoximation: Simpler Solution to Limit?

Tags: calculus, limits, pi, approximation-theory

May be a ridiculous question, but I wanted to see if MSE had "simpler" proofs for Viete's approximation (specifically, using an equation derived from Viete's formula) of $\pi$: $$\lim_{x \to \infty}2^x \left(\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 +\sqrt(2)+...} }}}\right) = \pi$$ for x square roots (and only one minus sign; rest are addition).

By "simpler," I'm sort of looking for a proof not using Viete's formulas at the least, but I would also like to know if it's possible to show this with more basic limit methods (e.g., Taylor Series(?), taking natural log, etc)

Thank you kindly!

Comment: What kind of Viete's formulas?

Comment: $\frac{2}{\pi} = \frac {\sqrt2}{2}* \frac {\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}{2}* \frac {\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}{2}*...$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the fact that 
$$\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\ldots+\sqrt{2}}}=2\cos\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}},$$
where $n$ is the number of radicals in LHS. Thus your sequence is
$$2^n\sqrt{2-2\cos\frac{\pi}{2^n}}=2^{n+1}\sin\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}\to \pi$$
as $n\to\infty$, since $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin\pi x}{x}=\pi.$$

Comment: +1 Amazing! Just out of curiosity, are there any other similar-looking formulas that are as slick as the one the top line for the cosine term involving a specified number of radicals?

Comment: @Xoque55 It's hard to recall any different formulas like this one... Maybe just more simple example like $\sqrt{a\sqrt{a\sqrt{\ldots\sqrt{a}}}}$, but nothing really slick.

Comment: @Gizmo Just an observation: $\sqrt{2+2\cos\frac{\pi}{2^n}}=\sqrt{4\cos^2\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}}=2\cos \frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}$. That's also an essence of a proof of this formula by induction.

Comment: @CuriousGuest Understood; I haven't seen that "version" using double-angle formulas. Thanks!